# I am not able to call rest api which is in another container running at localhost:9090, using localstack 12.5 lambda (running at 4566 port)

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, localstack

### localstack 12.5

dummy.py file for lambda hanlder

```
import sys
import requests

def handler(event, context):
    print("Inside handler")
    x = requests.get('http://localhost:9090/ping')
    print(x.status_code)
    return str(x.content)
```

In handler when i am calling get api which is in another container i am getting connection refused error.

Error:
"ConnectionError","errorMessage":"HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9090): Max retries exceeded with url:
Caused by NewConnectionError('\u003curllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff8185c8ad0\u003e: Failed to establish a new connection:

**However with postman I am able to hit http://localhost:9090/ping API**

Also If I replace x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com') then I am getting 200 .

Comment: Does the two Docker containers share a common network or do they both have host networking?

Comment: The issue has been resolved by adding below env variable in localstack

LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK="host"

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by adding below env variable in localstack

LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK="host"